# How can I sort a 2D array according to the 0th element of each subarray?

Tags: arrays, c, sorting, struct

I need to sort a matrix of 0's and 1's in such a way that the sum of its columns is in increasing order.

Input:

```
4 5      
0 0 1 1 0\n
1 1 1 0 1\n
0 1 1 1 0\n
1 0 1 1 0\n
```

Output:

```
0 0 0 1 1\n
1 1 1 0 1\n
0 0 1 1 1\n
0 1 0 1 1\n
```

I made a separate 2D array storing values of the sums and the initial indices of all the columns. If I'm able to sort the 2D array according to the sums and obtain the new index positions of all the columns, I can solve the problem. I'm using quicksort to sort the sums. But I don't know how to make sure that the index value remains attached to the sum.

I also thought of using structs but I'm not familiar with arrays of structs.

How can I solve this problem in C?

Comment: 1) Let's see your code.  2) For tricky sorting like this, sort an array of indices instead of the actual array.  The indices would start out numbered `0` to `n-1`, where `n` is the number of items to sort.  Then you swap the indices around instead of the actual data.

Comment: It isn't very clear what the sorting criterion is. You seem to have sorted each row, but I don't get why each row doesn't have all the zeros on the left of the ones.

Comment: @WeatherVane:  The output appears to be sorted by *column*, not row.  The first column has only a single `1`.  The second two columns each have 2 bits. The third column has 3 bits, and the last column has all bits.

Comment: @abelenky the columns in each diagram mostly have a different number of 0s and 1s. The question title says "according to the 0th element of each subarray" and I don't understand what that means.

Comment: Usually, rows are the major index and columns are subordinate. You could transpose the 4x5 matrix into a 5x4 matrix, use `qsort()` to sort the "subarrays" (rows), then transpose it back again. Trying to fiddle with values that reference where columns were and where they should be will be intricate and prone to errors. Then, decide if the `compare()` function only looks at the 0th element, or, as you write, calculates the "sum" of all elements in the row of the transposed matrix. Try it and post code if you have problems.